# Angular - List only populates with static values, not from variables

Tags: angular

My lists are only populated when I manually enter in static values for the variables, not when I get them from the forEach loop.

**TypeScript**

```
this.pinnedCCollection = this.afs.collection(pinnedCollection);
this.pinnedC = this.pinnedCCollection.valueChanges().do(item => {
    console.log('-------------');

    item.forEach(element => {

      // NOT WORKING
      // this.searchedS = element.s;
      // this.selectedT = element.t;
      // this.selectedC = element.c;

      // WORKING
      this.searchedS = 'static value 1';
      this.selectedT = 'static value 2';
      this.selectedC = 'static value 3';

      this.searchForA();  
    });

  });

searchForA(){
    var placeToSearch = 'SPlace/'+this.searchedS+'/TPlace/'+this.selectedT+'/CPlase/'+this.selectedC+'/APlace';

    this.aCollection = this.afs.collection(placeToSearch);
    this.a = this.aCollection.valueChanges();
 }
```

Comment: what is the `type` of item ? can you add a sample data ?

Comment: forEach((element: TypeOfElement) => ...

Comment: Niether of the variables `item` or `element` have types. Do I need it?

Comment: whats the structure of items? if they're objects you can't iterate them with forEach like they're an array? what's the specific error you're getting

Comment: I'm already iterating over each item with `forEach`, and I'm able to successfully log out the value of those elements inside of forEach and they are successfully saved into my local variables. Then `searchForA()` runs with the proper values in place, but the list on my webpage still comes up empty. The values from the properties of `element` seem to be perfectly fine.

Comment: How does `element` look like when you console.log it inside `forEach`?

Comment: `element` returns the full object like it should. See here for what I think the real culprit is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234400/typescript-global-function

Comment: Well I don't see anywhere that you would have user `function` so the context of `this` should be preserved. Could you please create a demo and I would be happy to take a look at it :)

Comment: I found the problem is actually getting each iteration in the `forEach` to execute one after another. I made another post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240860/angular-2-foreach-wait-until-previous-iteration-is-complete