# Typescript - Global function?

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, global

I'm trying to call a function from a 5-deep nested function in Typescript, and it's not able to see the outside function. Running `console.log(this)` inside of setTimeout returns the `window` object.

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {


lifeCycleFunc(){    //Function 1
    ...

    if() {                //Function 2
        ....

        var.do(item => {        //Function 3
            ....

            var.forEach(var => {      //Function 4
                ...

                setTimeout(function(){    //Function 5

                    this.searchFunc()        //this.searchForAssignments is not a function
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

searchFunc(){
    ...
}


}
```

Comment: Is this in a class? If so can we see the context of that class or if not then just drop the ‘this’ in front of searchFunc

Comment: Yes, this is in a class. I updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

`this` context inside `setTimeout` callback is going to be global object (`window`), but it should be `SearchComponent` class for this code to work correctly. To achieve that all nested functions including `setTimeout` callback should be arrow functions to bind `this` context correctly:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {    
    lifeCycleFunc(){
        ...

        if(condition) {
            ...

            foo.do(bar => {
                ...

                bar.forEach(baz => {
                    ...

                    setTimeout(() => {  
                        this.searchFunc();
                    }, 0);
                });
           });
       }
    }

    searchFunc(){
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: All my callbacks are already using arrow functions like you show. Running `console.log(this)` inside of setTimeout returns the `window` object for me.

Comment: @FiringBlanks Function 5 in your question is not an arrow function

Comment: The `setTimeout` is not an arrow function? How would I make it one then?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question and your comment about making it an arrow function, you do this:

```
setTimeout(() => {  
    this.searchFunc();
}, 0);
```

instead of:

```
setTimeout(function() {  
    this.searchFunc();
}, 0);
```

Comment: If you want to answer on a **comment**, you must set it as a **comment** under the one you are answering on it, because this is not an answer on the original question.

Comment: Yea well I can't add a comment because I don't have 50 rep, which is an absurd restriction. Oh and it does actually answer the question.

Comment: Ok, but the way you are answering is thought to be on the comment. However you can edit it to make it answering clearly the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var.forEach(var => {    //Function 3
            ...

            this.searchFunc()     //TypeError: this.searchForAssignments is not a function
        }.bind(this))
```

The `this` reference inside the `forEach` is the forEach function. You need to bind it to the this reference of the class.

Comment: it says 'cannot find name bind'. Do I have to import it from somewhere?

Comment: Oh wait that might not work on a lambda....... *sorry on my phone here. You wouldn’t need to import bind.

Comment: Are u by chance calling this like a static method? Like SearchSchoolComponent.lifeCycleFunc() ??

Comment: Nope, I was typing feverishly until I hit the `not a function` error on that very line. I'm not referencing this whole class from anywhere else.