# Angular 2 - ForEach wait until previous iteration is complete

Tags: angular, loops

I need a way of running .forEach() but I can't allow it to run over every iteration all at once. The first iteration needs to finish before the second starts, and the second needs to finish before the third starts, etc. As it is right now, each iteration will run simultaneously and flood my `runSearchFunc()`, making all three requests at once and overwriting the first two that didn't get a chance to wait for a response from the database. So I need to wait until the `runSearchFunc()` is completed before running the next interation.

```
  this.pinnedCollection = this.afs.collection(pinnedCollection);
  this.pinned = this.pinnedCollection.valueChanges().do(item => {

    item.forEach(element => {
        this.var1 = element.val1;
        this.var2 = element.val2;

        this.runSearchFunc();  
    }); 
  });

  runSearchFunc(){
      var placeToSearch = '...'
      this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection(placeToSearch);
      this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
  }
```

Comment: what does this.runSearchFunc() return?

Comment: Absolutely nothing

Comment: it subscribes to an observable that makes a server request?

Comment: `runSearchFunc()` fetches from my Firestore database so yeah, I do think it's an observable.  I'll update my code to show the function.

Comment: where and how do you subscribe to the observable chain?

Comment: I believe it's `valueChanges()`. I subscribed once to the `pinnedCollection` and once to the `itemsCollection`, so both `pinned` and `items` should essentially be treated as observables.